# I can't remove VSFTPD from the boot system in Kubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, ftp, vsftpd

I have a problem with VSFTPD on Kubuntu 14.04. I have the service installed, but I can't remove it from the boot system. I tried it many times with *“update-rc.d -f foobar remove”* but it remains booting with the system.

How do I remove VSFTPD from the boot system and starting the service manually? I searched a little, but I didn't found any solve, and I'm bored to try it.

I'm considering to switch to another FTP server if there is any easy to configure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This services starts as upstart to disable/manually start

```
$echo 'manual' | sudo tee -a /etc/init/vsftpd.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for sharing link, but this question was asked in StackExchange in past: [link to question](https://serverfault.com/questions/187696/ubuntuhow-to-not-run-vsftpd-at-boot-time)

Please let us know if it's hepled you. Following by your description you are on 14.04 and it still using initd, that's true for this answer in serverfault.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the service with this commands:

```
sudo service vsftpd stop
sudo mv /etc/vsftpd.conf /etc/vsftpd.conf.disabled
sudo mv /etc/init/vsftpd.conf /etc/init/vsftpd.conf.disabled
```

After then, make a test:

```
sudo service vsftpd start
ps xa | grep vsftp
```

Now no process should run.

You can do the whole thing undone:

```
sudo mv /etc/vsftpd.conf.disabled /etc/vsftpd.conf
sudo mv /etc/init/vsftpd.conf.disabled /etc/init/vsftpd.conf
sudo service vsftpd start
```